# C#: Store byte array in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, arrays

What would be a simple way to store a Byte[] array in XML (using C#) ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` to convert it to base 64 representation and store the resulting string.

You can get back the `byte[]` by calling `Convert.FromBase64String(string)` method.