# Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, bitmap

I want to **XML-Serialize** a complex type (class), that has a **property of type System.Drawing.Bitmap** among others.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the large icon, a 32x32 pixel image representing this face.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The large icon.</value>
    public Bitmap LargeIcon { get; set; }
```

I now have found out that serializing the Bitmap with the default XML serializer does not work, because it does not have a public parameterless constructor, which is mandatory with the default xml serializer.

I am aware of the following:

- There exists a workaround, posted here: http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/4759-XML-Serialization-C-Part-II-Images.aspx
  . However since this includes adding another property this seems to me a bit of a hack.
- There is also a deep XML serializing project on sourceforge.

I rather would not like referencing another project nor extensively tweak my class to just allow xml serialization of those bitmaps.

**Is there no way to keep that simple?**

Many thanks, Marcel

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public Bitmap LargeIcon { get; set; }

[Browsable(false),EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[XmlElement("LargeIcon")]
public byte[] LargeIconSerialized
{
    get { // serialize
        if (LargeIcon == null) return null;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            LargeIcon.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    set { // deserialize
        if (value == null) {
            LargeIcon = null;
        } else {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(value)) {
                LargeIcon = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the solution provided by the link in the original post. However to me, this still seems to be the most simple solution.

Comment: Frankly, it is the only sensible option with `XmlSerializer`. Implementing `IXmlSerializable` is asking for pain.

Comment: +1 for this solution. The source code works well for me. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have a little trouble using this code. Would the Byte array be automatically filled upon deserializing? And if yes, would I have to convert that array into a Bitmap afterwards? I currently get an "InvalidOperationException" when the deserializing gets to the line with the bmp. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dinoo - it should just work via the properties. Which .NET version are you using? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @Marc I am using 3.5. Would that make such a difference?

Comment: @Dinoo - no; given the date, that is most likely what I used when I wrote this answer... does the exception say anything else?

Comment: @Marc - Nope, it just states the exception and at which line in the xml file it occured. I guess I will post a question after I beat my head against the wall a little more.

Comment: An interesting thing that happened is I commented-out the "Get" part of the Byte[] and went without trouble even though I am only deserializing. However, the bitmaps are still null and a break point in the "Set" part never actually breaks. I am quite clueless now.

Comment: @Dinoo - if you remove the get *completely*, it will ignore the property. `return null;` would be a reasonable (if confusing) `get`

Comment: For posterity I am successfully using this method, except that instead of `LargIcon.Save` in `LargeIconSerialized.get` I have to use the `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter` method as used in this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xml_serializationasp.aspx

Comment: It dit not work for me. It tells "this xml writer does not support base64 encoded data" - So I changed the code a bit to apply this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938058/c-store-byte-array-in-xml

Comment: @Laurant which xml-writer implementation are you dealing with? it sounds very specific to that

Comment: It works for me, but it converts a Format32bppArgb to a Format32bppRgb, which is not what I want.

Comment: Doesn't work for me! I'm using a jpg to serialize! Get an ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: This works fine, but I would rather move the serialization logic in the Ignored property member to keep them apart the serialization process: a Bitmap object has to be properly disposed after use, and using this code as is causes memory leak in my scenario.

Comment: @Larry then... do that?

Answer (score 5):

<strike>You can also to implement `ISerializable` and to use `SerializationInfo` to deal manually with your bitmap content.</strike>

**EDIT:** João is right: Correct way to deal with XML serialization is to implement `IXmlSerializable`, not `ISerializable`:

```
public class MyImage : IXmlSerializable
{
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Name");
        writer.WriteString(this.Name);
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            this.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp );
            byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Image");
            writer.WriteBase64(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length);
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The BitMap class has not been designed to be easily XML Serialized. So, no, there's not simple way to correct a design decision.

Answer (score 2):

Implement `IXmlSerializable` and then handle all the serialization details yourself.

Since you say it's a large type and you only have a problem with the bitmap consider doing something like this:

```
public class BitmapContainer : IXmlSerializable
{
    public BitmapContainer() { }

    public Bitmap Data { get; set; }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class TypeWithBitmap
{
    public BitmapContainer MyImage { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not very practicable. This would involve a derived class and quite much code.