# View a serialized image class as a image data field (DataSet as datasource for DataGridView)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, .net-4.0, dataset

At first, thanks for reading my problem.

### **The Background**

Im working on a DataGridView which use a pre-existing XML file as datasource:

```
public DataSet TableDatabase = new DataSet();
TableDatabase.ReadXml("xml_file.xml");
(DataGridView)DbTable.DataSource = TableDatabase.Tables[0];
```

The base xml file is a generic database with id, int, text.

### **What I want to do**

What I basicly want to do, is to add a new column with typeof Bitmap (source from clipboard) **and** serialize it as Base64 "string".

If I use the first line "typeof(Bitmap)", the image data will be shown as image, but no idea how to serialize it...

```
// DataColumn col = TableDatabase.Tables[0].Columns.Add("columnname", typeof(Bitmap));
DataColumn col = TableDatabase.Tables[0].Columns.Add("columnname", typeof(MyImage));
```

I made a Class called "MyImage" (based on [Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)):

```
[Serializable]
public class MyImage : IXmlSerializable
{
    public Bitmap Image { get; set; }
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = reader.ReadContentAsBase64(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            if (ms == null)
            {
                ms = new MemoryStream(bytesRead);
            }
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        if (ms != null)
        {
            Image = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms,true,true);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();  
    }
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            byte[] bitmapData = ms.ToArray();
            writer.WriteBase64(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Its working really nice, I can load and write the imagedata in xml:

```
<columnname>...base64 data...</columnname>
```

### **The Problem**

The Datafield in the DataGridView will not show as image :(

It just shows a string: "**Namespace.MyImage**". So how can I tell the DataCell to show the image?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
 msdata:DataType="NAMESPACE.MyImage, APPNAME, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

Cast to MyImage Class, while

```
 msdata:DataType="System.Drawing.Bitmap, APPNAME, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

would cast the way to see the image. So I need to know how to define that MyImage target is a Bitmap... :(

### **Solved:**

I was really stupid ;)

```
    [XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public Bitmap Picture = new Bitmap(1, 1);

    // Serializes the 'Picture' Bitmap to XML.
    [XmlElementAttribute("Picture")]
    public byte[] PictureByteArray
    {
        get
        {
            TypeConverter BitmapConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Picture.GetType());
            return (byte[])BitmapConverter.ConvertTo(Picture, typeof(byte[]));
        }

        set
        {
            Picture = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(value));
        }
    }
```

And the Cell:

```
DataColumn col = TableDatabase.Tables[0].Columns.Add("columnname", PictureByteArray.GetType());
```