# C#: Why would an object that implements Serializable wouldn't be possible to serialize?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm running a desktop application and when I reach this line:

```
serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), value);
```

It's throws the following error:

```
There was an error generating the XML document.
```

This is the code:

```
public static string Serialize(object value)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(value.GetType());
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        serializer.Serialize(new StringWriter(sb), value);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

When I debug I see this in the Watch section:

```
    value.GetType().IsSerializable  true    bool
```

I'm setting this before declaring *values*'s class:

```
[Serializable]
```

Thank you in advance.

**Exception detail**

```
            System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
              Message="There was an error generating the XML document."
              Source="System.Xml"
              StackTrace:
                   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
                   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
                   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
                   at Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms.Controls.Utility.Serialize(Object value) in E:\Projects\Indexing\Main\Source\Pacer.PIA\Source\Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms\Controls\Utility.cs:line 55
                   at Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms.Controller.MainForm.ActionLoad..ctor(Int32[] index, Object objValue) in E:\Projects\Indexing\Main\Source\Pacer.PIA\Source\Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms\Controller\MainForm\ActionAdd.cs:line 37
                   at Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms.MainForm.SearchLoadByLoadNumber(String loadNumber) in E:\Projects\Indexing\Main\Source\Pacer.PIA\Source\Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms\Forms\MainForm.cs:line 3530
                   at Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms.MainForm.rmedtLoadNumber_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) in E:\Projects\Indexing\Main\Source\Pacer.PIA\Source\Pacer.PIA.UI.WindowsForms\Forms\MainForm.cs:line 1244
                   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBoxElement.textBoxItem_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at Telerik.WinControls.RadItem.OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadTextBoxItem.TextBoxControl_KeyPress(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadMaskTextBox.OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBox.WndProc(Message& m)
                   at Telerik.WinControls.UI.HostedTextBoxBase.WndProc(Message& message)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
                   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
              InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
                   Message="The type System.Drawing.Bitmap was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."
                   Source="niumy1xe"
                   StackTrace:
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write4_Image(String n, String ns, Image o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write5_BEDocument(String n, String ns, BEDocument o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write6_BERequirement(String n, String ns, BERequirement o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write8_BEMove(String n, String ns, BEMove o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write9_BELoad(String n, String ns, BELoad o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
                        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterBELoadCollection.Write10_ArrayOfBELoad(Object o)
                   InnerException:
```

The class:

```
    [Serializable]
public class BELoadCollection : List<BELoad>, ICloneable
{
    public BELoad FindByLoadId(string loadId)
    {
        return this.Find(load => load.LoadId.Equals(loadId));
    }

    public bool ExistsByLoadId(string loadId)
    {
        return this.Exists(load => load.LoadId.Equals(loadId));
    }

    public bool HasLoadsWithDocumentRequirementLinked
    {

        get
        {
            return this.Exists(load => load.HasDocumentsRequirementLinked);
        }
    }

    public void PrepareRequirementsToIndex()
    {
        this.ForEach(load =>
        {
            load.PrepareRequirementsToIndex();
        });

    }

    public bool HasLoadsReadyToIndex
    {

        get
        {
            return this.Exists(load => load.HasDocumentsRequirementReadyToIndex);
        }

    }

    public BERequirementCollection GetRequirementsReadyToIndex()
    {
        BERequirementCollection beRequirementsReadyToIndex = new BERequirementCollection();

        this.ForEach(load => beRequirementsReadyToIndex.AddRange(load.GetRequirementsReadyToIndex()));

        return beRequirementsReadyToIndex;
    }

    #region ICloneable Members

    object ICloneable.Clone()
    {
        return this.Clone();
    }

    public BELoadCollection Clone()
    {
        BELoadCollection BELoadCollectionClone = new BELoadCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i <= this.Count - 1; i++)
            BELoadCollectionClone.Add(this[i]);

        return BELoadCollectionClone;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And this is BELoad (just the fields)

```
 public class BELoad : BEMetaData, ICloneable
{
    //Fields
    private BEMoveCollection beMoveCollection;

    public string LoadId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
    public string VendorCityState { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentPrefix { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Driver { get; set; }
    public string Shipper { get; set; }
    public string ShipperCityState { get; set; }
    public string BillTo { get; set; }
    public string BillToCityState { get; set; }
    public string Consignee { get; set; }
    public string ConsigneeCityState { get; set; }
    public string Stop { get; set; }
    public string StopCityState { get; set; }
    public string Container { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could any of the nested type be generating malformed xml ?

Comment: What do you mean with malformed xml? How could this happen?

Comment: The inner exception should provide a bit more useful information.  Could you please post the full result (including stack traces) from the exception's ToString() method?

Comment: Please post the class- Did you read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx#trblshtxsd_topic3

Comment: Do what the messages says "The type System.Drawing.Bitmap was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically."

Comment: Where's the Bitmap in your code?

Comment: XmlSerializer is not even remotely interested in [Serializable] - it is not checked, and is not required

Comment: @AustinSalonen I found it very deep inside the class. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a hint in the stacktrace:

```
InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException                    
    Message="The type System.Drawing.Bitmap was not expected. 
    Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types 
    that are not known statically."
```

`System.Drawing.Bitmap`is not Xml Serializable, hence the exception. Perhaps another way would be to use `XmlIgnoreAttribute` to ignore this property, or implement `IXmlSerializable`and serialize the image as an ascii blob if you really need it saved?

> See the related question & answer [Serializing a Bitmap in C# to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)

*contributed by Conrad Frix in comments*

Comment: Here's an example of an implantation of what you described [Serialize a Bitmap in C#/.NET to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)

Comment: @ConradFrix thanks - if you put that as an answer I'll +1 it :D

Comment: Thanks :) but it would probably be better if you edited your answer since yours is probably going to be the one future users would see.

Answer (score 2):

The `Serializable` attribute is not related to XML serialization, it's for binary serialization. An object that is serializable with `BinaryFormatter` isn't always serializable with `XmlSerializer`...

Answer (score 0):

For XMLSerializer you must have a parameter-less contructor in the class which is getting serialized.

Note that BinaryFormatter and DataContractSerializer do not require this - they can create an uninitialized object out of the ether and initialize it during deserialization.

Comment: Does this answer the question?