# Serialize and Store an Image in an XML File

Tags: c#, wpf, image, serialization, observablecollection

Got a little bit of a problem. I have a program that builds an observable collection of Users. The User has a Firstname, Lastname, and Image. I can add the user to the observable collection, but I also want to save the collection and load it everytime I reopen the program.

My problem is that while its fairly easy to save a firstname and lastname, the writer can't write the image to the xml file. Is there any way around this?

Here's what I have so far:

the observable collection:

```
ObservableCollection<VendorClass> ProfileList = new ObservableCollection<VendorClass>();
```

the problematic writer:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<VendorClass>));
        using (StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter("vendors.xml")) //Data/customers.xml
        {
            xs.Serialize(wr, ProfileList);
        }
```

Any ideas? And if there does exist a solution to write in an image, is there a viable way to read it out again?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XmlSerializer can't serialize or deserialize the WPF image types like BitmapImage etc. It is however able to (de)serialize byte arrays. So you may add a `byte[] ImageBuffer` property to your Person class, which contains the binary image data. You would then also set the `XmlIgnore` attribute on the `Image` property to suppress its (de)serialization, and set `XmlElement("Image")` on the `ImageBuffer` properties to (de)serialize it as `<Image>...</Image>`.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public BitmapSource Image { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public byte[] ImageBuffer
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] imageBuffer = null;

            if (Image != null)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder(); // or some other encoder
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(Image));
                    encoder.Save(stream);
                    imageBuffer = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return imageBuffer;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                Image = null;
            }
            else
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(value))
                {
                    var decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(stream,
                        BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                    Image = decoder.Frames[0];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has also been suggested for properties of type Bitmap in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907165/1136211).

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying to figure this out and your answer has been the clearest and easiest so far. Worked perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. An alternative solution would be to have class User implement the `IXmlSerializable` interface, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1907113/1136211). You would however have to (de)serialize *all* properties of the class in that implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You would base64 encode the image to convert it to a string and then write that into a CDATA section.  See [How do you serialize a string as CDATA using XmlSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379888/how-do-you-serialize-a-string-as-cdata-using-xmlserializer)

Comment: Yikes. That points me in the right direction, but barely, and nowhere as far as in relation to the image.