# Data Serialization WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, deserialization

Sorry if this question seems silly. I have studied a few web pages on the subject but am unsure how relevant they are to my issue. I have a 2D map designer that i have made. I would like to save the map, so that i can load it and play a game on it. I'm very new to Serialization, and i was wondering what documents i should study and if someone could point me to some web pages that relate to my serialization task.  Here is the data structure:

```
    public class ModelMap
    {
        public ModelMap()
        {
            this.cellBgImage = new Image();
            this.exitImage = new Image();
            this.theseus = new Image();
            this.minotaur = new Image();
        }

        public int rows { get; set; }
        public int cols { get; set; }
        public int boardXPos { get; set; }
        public int boardYPos { get; set; }
        public int myCellSize { get; set; }
        public Image cellBgImage { get; set; }
        public string HorizontalWallSource { get; set; }
        public string VerticalWallSource { get; set; }
        public Image minotaur { get; set; }
        public Image theseus { get; set; }
        public Image exitImage { get; set; }
        public string exitCellPlacement { get; set; }
        public int myWidth { get; set; }
        public int myHeight { get; set; }
        private List<Cell> m_cells = new List<Cell>();
        public List<Cell> myCells
        {
            get
            {
                return m_cells;
            }
            set
            {
                m_cells = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cell Class:

```
public class Cell
    {
        public Cell(int col, int row, CellSide rightWall, CellSide bottomWall, ModelMap map)
        {
            this.myColumn = col;
            this.myRow = row;
            this.myRightWall = rightWall;
            this.myBottomWall = bottomWall;
            this.myMap = map;
        }

        public Cell(int col, int row, CellSide rightWall, CellSide bottomWall, ModelMap map, Image bgImage)
        {
            this.myColumn = col;
            this.myRow = row;
            this.myRightWall = rightWall;
            this.myBottomWall = bottomWall;
            this.myMap = map;
            this.myBgImage = bgImage;
        }

        public ModelMap myMap { get; set; }
        public Image myBgImage { get; set; }
        public bool hasMinotaur { get; set; }
        public bool hasTheseus { get; set; }
        public bool isExit { get; set; }
        public int mySize { get; set; }
        public CellSide myRightWall { get; set; }
        public CellSide myBottomWall { get; set; }
        public int myColumn { get; set; }
        public int myRow { get; set; }
    }

    public class CellSide
    {
        public CellSide(int hasWall, bool highlighted)
        {
            this.hasWall = hasWall;
            this.isHighlighted = highlighted;
        }

        public bool isHighlighted { get; set; }
        public int hasWall { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your model is OK and should have no problem serializing, except for the fact that you can't serialize the UI. Remove the `Image` properties and use a byte array or something to store your image data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read about standard [.NET serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) and examples of [XML serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You will need to make some changes to make serialization of those classes possible:

- `Cell` and `CellSide` must have parameterless constructors,
- `Image` (or rather its implementation) can't be directly serialized, but you can make some workaround (like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907077/serialize-a-bitmap-in-c-net-to-xml)) or just serialize file path to the images and load them after deserialization

Then you can serialize an object to the XML file:

```
var map = new ModelMap();
...
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ModelMap));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"e:\test.xml"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, map);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try and make those changes to my program. I read the document on .NET serialization. Do you think XML serialization is the more likely way to go, rather than binary serialization?

Comment: It all depends, binary serialization will hide details of the map and may contain bitmaps, but XML is more editable etc. But using binary serialization wouldn't change a lot in this code example, just use `BinaryFormatter` class similarly. You will also have to add `[Serializable]` attribute to the serialized classes.

Comment: Great :) For now i will study XML serialization and hopefully use that. It seems appropriate. Thanks.